# DevExtreme DataGrid ColorBox

Tags: devexpress

I am trying to make one of the cells in my datagrid display the "ColorBox" so users can choose a colour.

This is my model:

```
public class Colour : ModelWrapper
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string BorderColour { get; set; }
    public string BackgroundColour { get; set; }
    public string HighlightColour { get; set; }
    public string HighlightBorder { get; set; }
    public string HighlightBackground { get; set; }
}
```

This is the code for the grid:

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid<Colour>()
    .ID("GridView")
    .ShowBorders(true)
    .DataSource(d => d.Mvc().Controller("Colours").LoadAction("Get").DeleteAction("HardDelete").UpdateAction("Put").InsertAction("Post").Key("Id"))
                            .Columns(columns =>
                            {
                                columns.AddFor(m => m.Active);
                                columns.AddFor(m => m.Name);
                                columns.AddFor(m => m.BorderColour);
                                columns.AddFor(m => m.BackgroundColour);
                                columns.AddFor(m => m.HighlightColour);
                                columns.AddFor(m => m.HighlightBorder);
                                columns.AddFor(m => m.HighlightBackground);})

                            .Paging(p => p.PageSize(AppConstants.GridControlPageSize))
                            .FilterRow(f => f.Visible(true))
                            .HeaderFilter(f => f.Visible(true))
                            .GroupPanel(p => p.Visible(true))
                            .Grouping(g => g.AutoExpandAll(false))
                            .RemoteOperations(true)
                            .ColumnChooser(c => c.Enabled(true))
                            .StateStoring(s => s
                    .Enabled(true)
                    .Type(StateStoringType.LocalStorage)
                    .StorageKey(storageName))
                            .Editing(editing =>
                            {
                                editing.Mode(GridEditMode.Form);
                                editing.AllowAdding(true);
                                editing.AllowDeleting(true);
                                editing.AllowUpdating(true);
                            })
)
```

For example, here is one of the columns I want to enable users to use the ColorBox for:

```
columns.AddFor(m => m.BackgroundColour);
```

It appears that this should be possible looking at some example code here. (Admittedly this code is marked as "2 years old"):

```
settings.Columns.Add(column =>
{
    column.FieldName = "Colour";
    column.Caption = "Colour";
    column.Width = 100;

    column.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.ColorEdit;

    ColorEditProperties props = (ColorEditProperties)column.PropertiesEdit;
    props.ColumnCount = 8;
    props.EnableCustomColors = true;
    ColorEditItemCollection colours = new ColorEditItemCollection();
    colours.CreateDefaultItems(false);
    props.Items.Assign(colours);
});
```

It seems to be linked to the ColumnType property but when I look at the DevExtreme documentation the column object doesn't appear to have this property.

Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: Are you certain you are using devextreme? devextreme is supposed to be js only and this seems like C# razor code. Also giving the model you are binding would be helpful

Comment: @AntoniosKatopodis Thanks for taking the time to look. I have updated my question with additional info. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I dont have a machine which runs devextreme right now but the following should be correct.

```
.OnEditorPreparing("your_js_function")
```

Put this after columns:

```
.Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.AddFor(m => m.Active);
                            columns.AddFor(m => m.Name);
                            columns.AddFor(m => m.BorderColour);
                            columns.AddFor(m => m.BackgroundColour);
                            columns.AddFor(m => m.HighlightColour);
                            columns.AddFor(m => m.HighlightBorder);
                            columns.AddFor(m => m.HighlightBackground);})
.OnEditorPreparing("your_js_function")
```

Now a bit of explaination. This js function that you bind to the columns will run for each editor. All columns have a different editor which you can overwrite using this js function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function your_js_function(e) {
    if (e.dataField == "BackgroundColour") {
        e.editorName = "dxColorBox"; // Changes the editor's type
        e.editorOptions.onValueChanged = function (args) {
            // Implement your logic here

        }
    }
}
```

The official devexpress example is [here](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Widgets/DataGrid/Editing/#Customize_Editors) in the customize editors part. As you will see in the link there are other ways to achieve your result as well. I suggest using a debugger so you can see what **e** contains.

Also a tip when googling for errors devexpress unfortunately runs on many different versions (VB, C#, Jquery) I think the fastest way would be to find what you are looking for from the documentation.